# Rails 5: detect browser language

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to detect the browser language in order to set the appropriate i18n locale file.

This is the setup I have:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  before_action :set_locale

  ALLOWED_LOCALES = %w(de en en-US en-GB en-CA en-IN es).freeze
  DEFAULT_LOCALE = 'en-US'.freeze

  def extract_locale_from_header
    browser_locale = request.env['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE'].scan(/^[a-z]{2}/).first
    if ALLOWED_LOCALES.include?(browser_locale)
      browser_locale
    else
      DEFAULT_LOCALE
    end
  end
end

 private

  def set_locale
    I18n.locale = extract_locale_from_header
  end
```

Currently I have the browser language setup to english UK and this code:

```
browser_locale = request.env['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE'].scan(/^[a-z]{2}/).first
```

returns "en" instead of "en-GB".

How can I detect the exact language that I have setup in my browser?

Answer (score 0):

It returns 'en' because your regex is matching the first two chars. Change it to be something like `^[a-z]{2}(-[A-Z]{2})?`